# How to insert a formula in between sentences with a value result?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

How do I insert formula in between sentences with a dollar value formatting as the returned result? For example, in A3 I want to write:

="Total Invoice: $"&B1+B2

So the result should appear as "Total Invoice: $6,548.32"

However, when the formula is entered in excel, results come out as "Total Invoice: $6548.32375"

How can I control the result to only display 2 decimal points as well as the comma when required?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think chuff's suggestion will work, since the B2 value is appended to the number, not added. This is probably what you need:

```
="Total Invoice: "&text(B1+B2,"$#,##0.00")
```

Answer (score 2):

**DOLLAR** function will display your default currency, e.g.

`="Total Invoice: "&DOLLAR(B1+B2)`

Answer (score 0):

This formula will give the proper formatting:

```
    ="Total Invoice: "&TEXT(B1,"$#,##0.00")&B2
```

Note that the dollar sign is taken care of in the format specified in the TEXT function, so no need to include it in the initial string.

You can find more information about the TEXT function [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-function-HP010062580.aspx).